# HOW to Set Login FORM Alert Message, "Fake Login Form"?

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication

I want the following message to appear (in red text below the button) when a user clicks on the "submit" button: "Invalid Password. Please contact us for assistance." - This login form is not meant to be functional, so this message should show up no matter what they enter in to the username/password fields.

What should I do for this?

Here the code:
Many Thanks Before

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="singlecontent">
<form>
    <p>
        <label>Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password<br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" /></label>
    </p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" tabindex="100" />
    </p>

</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: I want this using javascript/Jquery so.. when I click submit the loading icons is appears and then warning message to on the bottom or nice popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="submit">
<input onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHtml='your message';" type="submit" name="wp- submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" tabindex="100" />
<div style="color:red;" id="msg"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working. Have you try this?